# Trouble implementing Maven in STS

Tags: maven, path, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am new to the **SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)** and am having trouble getting functions like `perform tests` or `perform package` to work.

I usually get an error that states:

> CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

I figured out it has something to do with Maven and adding it to the Path, but I cannot seem to find where to implement the environment variable for `MAVEN_HOME` successfully. Everywhere I have looked tells me something different and hasn't worked so far.

Comment: Try Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables.  I believe to get the Maven plugin to work, you have to add M2_REPO that points to your maven repository in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check if you can run `mvn` from your shell. For `mvn` to be available from your shell, you need to have the `M2_HOME/bin` added into your `PATH` variable.

For more information on installing and configuring Maven, please see the following link.

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation

Also note that `perform tests` and `perform package` are not Maven commands and they are expected to be executed from your Spring Roo console.

Answer (score 0):

Try going to  Preferences -> Maven -> Installations.  Make sure that the selected installation actually exists.

Comment: I checked that and the installation exists.
There are three boxes checked:
> Do not automatically update dependencies from remote repositories
> Download repository index updates on update
> Update Maven projects on start up

Comment: OK, then, check your error logs.  Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log.  Paste any relevant errors in the question.